# can't the play function to work in jquery script (joomla 2.5)

Tags: jquery, joomla, onclick

This jquery script works in a static website but only partially in joomla 2.5

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
...
//script here changes text color on hover - it works
...
  var audioIsPlaying = false;
  jQuery("span").click(function (event) {
    if(audioIsPlaying != true) {
      var elementID = event.target.id;
      var oggVar = "audio/"+elementID +".ogg";
      var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar); 
      audioElement.play();
      audioIsPlaying = true;
      audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
          audioIsPlaying = false;    
      });
    };
  });
});
```

The part of the script which causes text color change on hover works and has been omitted. 
The problem is that the script which is supposed to evoke an audio file when text is clicked on does not work in joomla (but works in static html.
I've checked oggVar and audioIsPlaying and they are being assigned values correctly. oggVar is set a path and audioIsPlaying true false.
I'm puzzled as to why the script works in a static website but not in joomla.
Other aspects of this script has been posted on recently, I'm grateful for the help received, thanks

Comment: try using the following for a relative path: 
`var oggVar = <?php JURI::root(); ?>"components/path_to_file/audio/"+elementID +".ogg";`

Comment: var oggVar = <?php JURI::root(); ?>"templates/beez_20/audio/"+elementID +".ogg";    this doesn't work, it stopped the hover function too. I'm running joomla on localhost with  audio files in templates/beez_20 (as the above path shows)